# Simple Recursion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to understand recursion in Haskell. I want to write a simple recursive function with the following properties: if `x > 50` then `rec(x) = x - 5` and `rec(x) = rec(rec(x+10))` otherwise.
This is what I came up with:

```
rec x = if x > 50
    then x-5
    else rec (rec (x+10))
```

The not recursive part seems to work fine, but the recursion doesn't. Every number less than 50 just return 50. For example `rec 60 = 55` `rec 40 = 50` `rec 25 = 50`

Any suggestions on how to fix my code would be appreciated.

Comment: Irrelevant to your problem, but I'd look into guards. They'd make your function much cleaner (subjectively).

Comment: I would also advocate for guards (`rec x | x > 50 = x - 5`) and then I would suggest you also explain what you expect the function to return, because to me it seems working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

For `x <= 50`, your function is equivalent to:

```
rec' x = if x `mod` 5 == 0
         then 50
         else 45 + x `mod` 5
```

This can be checked by running a simple test:

```
all (\ x -> rec x == rec' x) [0..50]
```

As a consequence, you need to feed an input which is not a multiple of 5 to get an answer distinct from 50.